# How do I override a magento 2 theme's phtml with my own custom theme?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, theming

I'm attempting to customise the ultimo theme (although presumably this would apply to any magento theme). I have created a new custom theme which (using theme.xml) uses Infortis/ultimo as it's parent.

Ultimo has the following path for it's header.phtml

```
ultimo/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

I've tried a number of different options for my theme to override this - none of which appear to work e.g.

```
frontend/my_theme/default/template/html/header.phtml
frontend/my_theme/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have selected your custom theme as current theme from admin also you have to run setup:upgrade command after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your theme.xml you set the parent the as  Infortis/ultimo

```
  <parent>Infortis/ultimo</parent>
```

just like
/Infortis/ultimo/template/page/html/header.phtml

/Custom/Theme/template/page/html/header.phtml

please clear and flush cache

and deploy and give permission

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

sudo chmod 777 -R var/ pub/media pub/static

Note: dont' forget to set Store Them As your custom created theme..

**registration.php Code**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Custom/Theme',
__DIR__
```

);

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>New Custom</title>
<parent>Infortis/ultimo</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
</media>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the theme path to override your template

Like `app/design/<Vendor>/<Package>/<Module_Package>/templates/your.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using magneto 1.X (By your reference code)

**In Magento 1.X**

First you should configure your new `package/theme` in the backed.

```
System -> Configuration -> Design -> Package = my_theme

Themes: default (no change should be necessary)
```

Now you can modified file `header.phtml`

```
app\design\frontend\my_theme\default\template\html\header.phtml
```

**In Magento 2**

```
app\design\frontend\<VENDOR_NAME>\<THEME_NAME>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\header.phtml
```